# Minmax нормализация на скользящем окне

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, анализ-данных

Как красиво нормализовать данные(0-1) на скользящем окне(5)?

Сейчас есть стандартный нормализатор, нормализующий по всему датасету `a`:

```
c = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(a['Start'])
```

Так, разумеется, выдает ошибку:

```
c = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(a['Start'].rolling(5))` -
```

Пример входных данных (слева - входной столбец, справа - то, что хочу получить на выходе):

[image: Слева - входной столбец, справа - то что хочу получить на выходе]

Comment: а почему не нормализовать до скользящего окна?

Comment: выдает ошибку, т.к. датасет {a} - это пандасдатафрейм с большим количеством столбцов

Comment: может приведете пример входных данных и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе? ;)

Comment: привела :) пример

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
In [130]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

In [131]: mms = MinMaxScaler()

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
   Start
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5     10
6      5
7    100
8     10
9      5

In [133]: df["StartNorm"] = mms.fit_transform(df[["Start"]])

In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   Start  StartNorm
0      1   0.000000
1      2   0.010101
2      3   0.020202
3      4   0.030303
4      5   0.040404
5     10   0.090909
6      5   0.040404
7    100   1.000000
8     10   0.090909
9      5   0.040404
```

Или так:

```
In [138]: mms.fit_transform(df[["Start"]].rolling(5).mean())
Out[138]:
array([[       nan],
       [       nan],
       [       nan],
       [       nan],
       [0.        ],
       [0.07826087],
       [0.10434783],
       [0.94782609],
       [1.        ],
       [1.        ]])
```

Comment: первый вариант я применяла - он работает ко всему датафрейму, не к окну данных. второй вариант, берет среднее значение, нужно текущее. т.е. Как число соотносится к коридору 5 последних чисел.

Comment: `т.е. Как число соотносится к коридору 5 последних чисел` - можете это пояснить  подробнее?

Comment: Например текущее число x=10. Диапазон последние 5 чисел вместе с текущим числом  это: 0,3,4,100,10. Тогда, то что я хочу получить для x это: (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) = (10-0)/(100-0) = 0.1  :)